# Domain Driven Design - Aggregates - EventPublisher with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-handling, domain-driven-design

I would like to ask about using EventPublisher inside aggregate.

```
class SomeAggregate
{

    private $eventPublisher;

    public function __construct(EventPublisher $eventPublisher)
    {
        $this->eventPublisher = $eventPublisher;
    }


}
```

When I create SomeAggregate I pass EventPublisher to the constructor and everything goes fine.

But what about when I retrieve this object from database.
Doctrine makes reconstruction of the object based on the fields from table and will skip EventPublisher.

How to make Doctrine  inject EventPublisher every time it retrieves SomeAggregate from database?

My prefered way, if such exists, is to map $eventPublisher property to EventPublisher class.

Comment: Basically you can't.  However, take a look at this approach: http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/07/24/doctrine_and_domainevents.html

Comment: Thanks mate. I don't like such way of handling events, where event are not standalone classes and I am coupled do doctrine hardly, but with a bit of modification I can use this approach. Firstly I will change event to a class, secondly I will keep array of events as property in the class ( exactly like in the example). Next thing I will have method for returning events from aggregate and all child entities. So from outside of the domain I will collect those events and publish them.

Answer (score 3):

With a **Doctrine Event Listener**.

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\EventPublisherInjector
        arguments: [@event_publisher_service_id]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

In `AppBundle\EventListener\EventPublisherInjector`:

```
public function __construct(EventPublisher $eventPublisher)
{
    $this->eventPublisher = $eventPublisher;
}

public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof SomeAggregate) {
         $entity->setEventPublisher($this->eventPublisher);
    }
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload

Comment: Your answer is good, but thanks to @Cerad I found better solution :)